# Set static head view in android ListView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am developing android application and i have follow problem.
My application has a static part(head),within located logo,search...  .
The problem is that, when I am adding listview to below of this head , the head view doesn't scrolling.
The head view and ListView located in LinearLayout.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
yourListView.addHeaderView(yourHeaderView);
```

Reference is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29)

Comment: I wrote this code by something wrong. View v = activity.findViewById(R.layout.newsfeed_head);
  
   
  lv =  (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.News_item_LV);
  lv.addHeaderView(v);
  
  
  
  lv.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
   
  adapter=new NewsFeedAdapter(activity,NewsList);
 
  lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Do you have the exception ?

Maybe the problem is that your header view is already a subview of the primary LinearLayout. Have you try to inflate the header from another XML ? Or remove the header from its parent before adding it to the ListView ?